# Terraform: Cloudwatch Canary Synthetics, How to create metric alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I try to create an alarm for my canary resource. I can't find a solution to reference my canary in my resource for `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm`. In the console there is a parameter `CanaryName`

I can create my canary with:

```
resource "aws_synthetics_canary" "some" {
  name                 = "some-canary"
  artifact_s3_location = "s3://some-bucket/"
  execution_role_arn   = "some-role"
  handler              = "exports.handler"
  zip_file             = "test-fixtures/lambdatest.zip"
  runtime_version      = "syn-1.0"

  schedule {
    expression = "rate(0 minute)"
  }
}
```

And with `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` I want to create the alarm to the associated canary but I am missing a parameter like CanaryName:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "foobar" {
  alarm_name                = "terraform-test-foobar5"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "2"
  metric_name               = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace                 = "AWS/EC2"
  period                    = "120"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = "80"
  alarm_description         = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
}
```

Namespace CloudWatchSynthetics is working

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Similar question: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/aws-cloudwatch-metric-alarm/14396

Comment: Was this added recently to CloudWatch?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? It's hard to know what issue you've ran into without seeing the Terraform code and/or hat you've done to replicate it in the AWS console. Have you also looked at both https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/synthetics_canary and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSynthetics/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteCanary.html?

Comment: @MarkoE I think it is not super new but some features (e.g. env variables) were added November last year and there are some urgent feature reqeusts open in the GitHub repo of terraform

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes I'll edit the question sorry

Comment: Well, you pasted Terraform examples. Can you please share *your* code, with removing anything sensitive, like bucket name?

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference because I don't know how to use `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` with canaries, so nothing for that exists. The canary is working I just don't find a way to refer it in the alarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  dimensions = {
    CanaryName = "NAME_OF_CANARY"
  }
```

That's how you reference a canary name :-)